# EmberJS computed `and` negation

Tags: typescript, ember.js

I have a class with properties:

```
import { and, not } from '@ember/object/computed';

EmberObject.extend({
    a: false,
    notA: not('a'),

    b: true,
    c: true,
    d: and('b', 'c', 'notA')
});
```

So `d` relies on the negation of `a`.

Is there a notation to do something like `d: and('b', 'c', '!a')` so that I don't need the redundant `notA` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a notation to do something like...

no. You can however programm the complete computed:

```
d: computed('a', 'b', 'c', function() {
  return !this.a && this.b && this.c;
}),
```

however you could just build this yourself with something like this:

```
function betterAnd(...props) {
  const positiveDeps = props
    filter(x => !x.startsWith('!'));
  const negativeDeps = props
    .filter(x => x.startsWith('!'))
    .map(x => x.substr(1));
  return computed(...positiveDeps, ...negativeDeps, function() {
    return [
      ...positiveDeps.map(x => this.get(x)),
      ...negativeDeps.map(x => !this.get(x)),
    ].reduce((a, b) => a && b, true);
  });
}
```

and then you can just do `d: betterAnd('b', 'c', 'notA')`.

Comment: I just went with the simple computed. KISS is the way to go if it's not already built in IMO

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`ember-awesome-macros`](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-awesome-macros), which supports composing macros:

```js
import { and, not } from 'ember-awesome-macros';

EmberObject.extend({
    a: false,
    b: true,
    c: true,
    d: and('b', 'c', not('a'))
});
```

Comment: I like the library, however, it's just a bit too big. All I need is the `not` part and so installing a giant library like that is overkill IMO